# Performing Random-Forest Classification of 10cm Imagery for species-distribution in R (no point-shapes)?

Tags: raster, r, classification, digital-image-processing, random-forest

I'm trying to classify 10cm-resolution images with the RF-package.

I do this to separate some species in the forest, seen on my images.

While I was searching for an answer, I found the following code, bit I don't understand why the images have to be transformed into point-shapes, so I'm looking for a way to perform a RF-classification just with Raster (*tif, *png).

The code I found (made by Mr. Evans):

---

```
    require(sp)
    require(rgdal)
    require(raster)
    require(randomForest)

# CREATE LIST OF RASTERS
    rlist=list.files(getwd(), pattern="img$", full.names=TRUE) 

# CREATE RASTER STACK
    xvars <- stack(rlist)      

# READ POINT SHAPEFILE TRAINING DATA
    sdata <- shapefile("inshape.shp")

# ASSIGN RASTER VALUES TO TRAINING DATA
    v <- data.frame(extract(xvars, sdata))

# RUN RF MODEL
## assumeing that sdata has a variable called 'train' with e.g. 0 and 1 values 
    rf.mdl <- randomForest(x=v, y=as.factor(sdata$train))
## or for regression:
    rf2 <- randomForest(x=v, y=sdata$train)        

# CHECK ERROR CONVERGENCE
    plot(rf.mdl)

# PLOT mean decrease in accuracy VARIABLE IMPORTANCE
    varImpPlot(rf.mdl, type=1)

# PREDICT MODEL
    predict(xvars, rf.mdl, filename="RfClassPred.img", type="response", 
        index=1, na.rm=TRUE, progress="window", overwrite=TRUE)
```

---

My Questions:

1. At "Read Point Shapefile Training Data", why can't I use just raster?
   I don't get the "jump" to point-shape
2. In my understanding, I need to create a raster-stack and some training-areas, which are imported as raster's as well. Then I perform rf-classification and plot the results.

Am I right?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with your classification?

Comment: I want to find areas of 2 tree species(homogeneous areas), I found in person. I marked them with a GPS and made training-areas out of it. Now i want to classify this image with RF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script is configured to take a point shapefile of training data and use that to train a Random Forest classifier.  The screenshot shows the form the shapefile attribute table needs to take in order to be used as a training set.

[image]

The important fields here are 1) the XY coords, 2) the pixel values for each band at that XY coordinate, and 3) the class of vegetation (e.g. juniper, grass, etc).  You can see that I also added an NDVI band into the raster stack, which can increase your classifier performance.

The following script is a simplified version of the one you posted, where I did all data manipulation in a GIS.  The general workflow to produce the training data:

1. Generate shapefile from your GPS data and make sure to calculate the
   XY coords in the attribute table in addition to the class (e.g.
   juniper).
2. Sample all of the bands in the imagery and write to the shapefile attributes. 
   You can accomplish this in ArcGIS using the Sample tool.  A word of
   caution here:  ArcGIS has, in the past, had bugs with the Sample
   tool.  R's `extract` function in the `raster` package is considered a better alternative.
3. Write attributes to a .CSV file.
4. Read .CSV file into R and use as training data set for the RF classifier.

Of course, all of the principles of classifying remotely sensed data apply here: sample size matters, training data should be generated relatively equally among classes, sampling plots should be distributed throughout scene, high accuracy GPS devices are best...

---

```
require(sp)
require(rgdal)
require(raster)
require(randomForest)

# Set the working directory
setwd("C:/path/to/folder/containing/imagery")

# CREATE LIST OF RASTERS
rlist=list.files(getwd(), pattern="img$", full.names=TRUE) 

# CREATE RASTER STACK
rasters = stack(rlist)

intable = read.csv("C:/path/to/comma/separated/value/file.txt")

myrf = randomForest(factor(class) ~ band1 + band2 + band3 + band4 + ndvi, data = intable, ntree = 2500)

predict(rasters, myrf, filename="outFileName.img", type="response",
        index=1, na.rm=TRUE, progress="window", overwrite=TRUE)
```

Comment: but how can points with 2 coordinates be training-areas? btw: good explanation

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit @user2999399?

Comment: usually like in maximum-like.-classification, the classifier needs training-areas. these areas are small triangles or circles which are made to represent the class.
when we now use points( just x and y coord.) how is the classifier able to see the pixel classes? 
does it use a small area around the points?

Comment: The methods you are describing are common to packages like Erdas where you can grow regions of similar pixel values into a polygon, or define specific polygons by hand that make up a sample in a class.  Usually the MLC algorithm takes the mean value of these polygon regions of similar pixels.  In this RF case, the coordinates mark individual pixels, which are then used in the algorithm to define what makes up a particular class.  This is why it is important to have a large sample size and make sure to use "pure" pixels that make up that class.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, since I try to identify single species in a closed treecanopy in an area of 5x5 kilometers where 1 pixel represents 10cm. Just for my understanding: So the classifier decides with the vast amount of sample-pixel which class the pixel belongs to? -is it helpful to filter the single bands and fill the raster-stack with dozents of filtered bands?

Comment: That is exactly the idea here--RF uses a training set to predict the class of all of the other pixel values.  I would not recommend adding filtered bands to the stack.  By the way, what type of imagery are you using and how many spectral bands do you have?

Comment: I have 5 bands. digital orthophotographs, as mentioned 10cm resolution.
So I just have to add the bands and a huuuge amount of trainingpixel in the csv-file to give it a good go?
How about the results? Does R give me a plotted Raster in return, or just some %-values?

Comment: Great, you likely have good spectral resolution for the classification.  I would recommend reading p.67 of Classification Methods for Remotely Sensed Data, Second Edition to determine the proper number of training samples: http://books.google.com/books?id=oXpzROm11QMC&pg=PA67&lpg=PA67&dq=congalton+rules+of+thumb+for+training+data+samples&source=bl&ots=AUsTIQ9X2y&sig=lg3ZUSnJgIv-YyFqZoCgDXVJ2Ms&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ThrxU61_4tbwAevpgagN&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=congalton%20rules%20of%20thumb%20for%20training%20data%20samples&f=false

Comment: Concerning the x/y coordinates in the *.csv. where do they come from? I guess they are not the etrs98/utm coordinates, am I wrong?
With the identification-tool(the little blue i in Arcmap) I can only read UTM coordinates or whatever reference they got. So where can I extract plain x and y coords?

Comment: @user2999399 Remember, the XY coords simply mark the point used to "drill down" and extract the underlying raster band values.  There are several ways you can add the XY coords.  In this case, I used the Add XY Coordinates (Data Management) tool in ArcGIS to get the coords.  These coordinates will be in whatever format your base feature class is in.  You can also do this in R, but that is a case for a new question.

Comment: code works, but I get a failure: 
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'band1' not found
I have no typo in my .csv, my colums are "FID OBJECTID band1 band2 band3 class X Y"

Comment: code: 
require(sp)

require(rgdal)

require(raster)

require(randomForest)

setwd("D:/BA-Workspace/DOP_10/orthophotos_abcd/R/test_run_R")

rlist=list.files(getwd(), pattern="tif$", full.names=TRUE) 

rasters = stack(rlist)

intable = read.csv("D:/BA-Workspace/DOP_10/orthophotos_abcd/R/pointdata_sw_aug.csv")

myrf = randomForest(factor(class) ~ band1 + band2 + band3 , data = intable, ntree = 2500)

predict(rasters, myrf, filename="outFileName.img", type="response",
        index=1, na.rm=TRUE, progress="window",
 overwrite=TRUE) 
Any ideas?

Comment: Your band names in the script and .csv must match exactly.

Comment: so FID and OBJECTID are wrong here?

Comment: FID and OBJECTID can stay... makes no difference. 
well, my columns are named like the columns in my *csv. 
just band1 band2 band3 without space or just seperated by commas like all entries.

Comment: One nice thing in the raster package is you can now assign names to the bands in a raster stack object that will be honored in the predict funciton. This means that if the band names do not match your training data names you can just assign the correct names to the raster object.

Comment: The idea behind using areas rather than points to train a classification is to control sample variance. This can be both a good or bad thing depending on the model and the sample. Using the R extract function you could define a focal window and a statistical function (eg., mean) to smooth the variation which, would functionally emulate region grow.